# Need help in VB.net 2005 to perform logic when the Enter key is pressed

Tags: vb.net

I would like to display a `MessageBox` anytime the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed. I have done this in `vb.net` 2013, but when trying to do the equivalent in `vb.net` 2005, I am not having success.

Below, I show the code for creating the column in the `Form_Load` subroutine. Then, I gave the code for the `Qty_change` subroutine.

Then, I have an alternate version of `Qty_change` heading. For both `QTY_CHANGE`, I have displayed the error I get. What is the correct code?

```
SUB LOAD

...ETC ETC...

quantityItem = New ScrollableListItem((My.Resources.Resource.StrQuantity & ":" & vbTab) + quantityText, Nothing, Nothing, "quantity")
quantityItem.EditControl = textBox
quantityItem.Validator = quantityValidator
AddHandler quantityItem.ItemChanged, AddressOf QTY_Change
END SUB

Sub QTY_Change(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
If e.KeyValue = 13 Then
  MessageBox.Show("Response")
End If
End Sub
```

> Error: 'KeyValue' is not a member of 'System.EventArgs'

```
Sub QTY_Change(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
```

> Error: Method 'Public sub QTY_CHange' does not have the same signature as delegate 'Delegate Sub EventHandler(sender as object,e as system.eventargs)'

Comment: I just want to point out that you've asked 11 questions and never once accepted any answers.  That doesn't really encourage anyone to help you out.

Comment: Well MrZander if you had given an answer that would have actually solved my issue than I would have accepted your answer.

Comment: This isn't a place for being rude. You're now further discouraging anyone from answering and helping you out - _Be Nice!_

Comment: I agree David. Please be nice. If you have an answer, please post it and I will appreciate the suggestion. If you just want to read my history to post some discouraging remarks about my questions, please move on.

Comment: He was trying to give you feedback. Accepting answers shows you appreciate the help you are given. People expect the OP to accept an answer if it helped, or at the very least upvote it if it didn't fully solve the issue. He noticed you'd not been doing that, so people can be put off trying to be helpful if you're not going to give anything back.

Comment: You havent read [ask] or taken the [tour], so pointing out low  participation metrics (2 votes in 2 years, no reviews etc) ought not be a suprise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well of course you're going to get an error on the `AddHandler` method - `KeyPress EventArgs` are required to do what you're trying to do, not `System EventArgs`.

In your `Form_Load` event, you need something along the lines of this

```
Me.KeyPreview = True
AddHandler Me.KeyDown, AddressOf QTY_Change
```

Then, change your `QTY_Change` code to be something along the lines of:

```
Private Sub QTY_Change(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        MessageBox.Show("Response!", "", MessageBoxStyle.OK)
    End If
End Sub
```